# Convert Setup Script (BASH) To Ask Password Only Once?

Tags: linux, bash, automation

I have a script that I use to set up my laptop automatically with all of my settings. I experiment with different Linux distributions constantly on this laptop, so it is very useful to have a script like this to pull in all my settings fresh after an install. It works well, but it asks for my password multiple times. I know it's because I'm using scp multiple times, but I'm not quite sure if maybe my password can be cached and reused for the rest of the script after the first entry?

Here is the script:
http://pastebin.com/gHFr91Lf

Answer (score 2):

Create a "null" SSH session in the background that generates a master connection (see the `ControlPath` and `ControlMaster` options in the `ssh_config(5)` man page). Using the same control settings for each SSH/SCP operation will use the existing connection instead of reauthenticating with the server. Don't forget to kill the null session once the script is done.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would defeat the purpose. The idea is to be able to run my script against a fresh install of a distribution. If I have to modify config files to get the script to function, I may as well do the entire thing manually. Is there a way to cache the password without relying on the config file?

Comment: @jlacroix82: Have you looked at the doumentation for `ssh` yet? Specifically the `-o` flag?

Comment: Yes, I have read through it but I don't see anything that specifically mentions what I'm asking for unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The second sentence of my answer goes over this.