# Ask for password once during dotfile installation

Tags: bash, passwords

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/462667/convert-setup-script-bash-to-ask-password-only-once), I'm making dotfiles for setup of a fresh OS X machine. It asks for my password multiple times, since install & system setting sudo commands are in several nested scripts. Any way I can cache the password once?

The dotfiles are based off of Zach Holman's and can be found [here](https://github.com/JoshuaJBerk/dotfiles).

Mathias Bynens has an OSX script with similar purpose with `sudo -v` and 
`while true; do sudo -n true; sleep 60; kill -0 "$$" || exit; done 2>/dev/null &`

...the problem is that none of these carry on into the other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can make *sudo* last a tad longer, better not a whole tad longer for obvious security reasons.

Edit the file /etc/sudoers with the command

```
  sudo visudo
```

(Warning: you cannot use any other editor/command to do this, anything else will leave your system seriously damaged), then change the line

```
  Defaults      env_resets
```

into

```
 Defaults      env_resets,timestamp_timeout=10
```

This will let the effect last 10 mnutes. If instead you wish to have an immediate exit from sudo, you should use *sudo -k command* .

Comment: I'd prefer to have the behavior remain in the script, like not editing system-wide default settings for Sudo, if I can avoid it. That seems like playing with fire to me. The problem is that from within one script, another is called from a different file, which kills the sudo auth. Can it be 'passed along' somehow? Make sense?